# show count value from mysql column?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to show the count value from a column in my table.

my table is called ptb_forum, and it looks like this:

```
id  |  from_user_id  |  content  |  title  |  read_forum  | deleted

1           3            hello      test           20          0
2           6            bored      hello          40          0
```

i am basically trying to get the number in read_forum (so 20 or 40 or whatever) to echo out in php by using this mysql code:

```
function check_new_forum2() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) read_forum FROM ptb_forum WHERE ptb_forum.read_forum=ptb_forum.from_user_id AND ptb_forum.deleted='0' 
        ";
            $check_new_forum_set2 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($check_new_forum_set2);
            return $check_new_forum_set2;       
        }
```

and echoing out the result using this php:

```
$check_new_forum_set2 = check_new_forum2();
while ($newf = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_forum_set2)) {

    echo "<div class=\"forum_comments\">". $newf['COUNT(id)'] ."&nbsp;Views</div>";
 } ?>
```

at the moment nothing is being echoed, and i dont know where im going wrong, im new to mysql and am only just learning count, can someone please show me where im going wrong.
thanks

Comment: mysql_* are depricated please dont rely on them

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id)  AS c` and use `$newf['c']`

Comment: Are you checking for MySQL errors?  I think I see at least one syntax error, you need a comma at least:  `COUNT(id), read_forum`

Comment: Ah, without the comma you're setting `COUNT(id) AS read_forum`

Answer (score 3):

Because you haven't got a comma between `SELECT COUNT(id)` and `read_forum` your sql is doing this

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS read_forum
```

So you need to use `$newf['read_forum']` **or do this if read_forum is a column:**

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS c, read_forum
```

and use

```
$newf['c']
```

Comment: I was not sure if `read_forum` was a column either, but this was going to be my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `$query` if it returns false. If so there is an error in your SQL.

Perhaps the select statement should have read:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), read_forum FROM ptb_forum
WHERE ptb_forum.read_forum=ptb_forum.from_user_id
AND ptb_forum.deleted=0
```

if ptb_forum.deleted is a number and not a string

Answer (score -1):

Use `$newf['read_forum']` instead of `$newf ['count(id)']`
 I don't think there is any use of count(Id) in the query